# R - confusionMatrix() - Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to do coursera project on practical machine learning using train() with random forests. However I'm getting 2 issues. Since the original dataset is quite big, I replicated the issue with 2 small dataframes as you can see below.

Input

```
library(caret)
f = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
f2 = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
fit <- train(y~., data = f, method="lm")
pred <- predict(fit, newdata = f2)
confusionMatrix(pred, f2)
```

Output (main problem)

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

If I use the `table` function instead of the `confusionMatrix`, I get the following:

```
Error in table(pred, data = f2) : all arguments must have the same length
```

Though `pred` is of length 5 and `f2$y` is of length 5 as well.

As a side note, the function for fit in this example, occasionally also gives me an error which I also don't understand.

```
Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

EDIT: grammar

Comment: `confusionMatrix(pred, f2$y)`

Comment: tried that before
`Error in confusionMatrix.default(pred, f2$y) : the data cannot have more levels than the reference`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got three issues.

1. `confusionMatrix` is expecting two vectors, but `f2` is a data frame. Instead, do `confusionMatrix(pred, f2$y)`.
2. But that gives a different error: `The data must contain some levels that overlap the reference.`. Which raises the second issue. If you look at the predictions and actual values for `f2`, there's no overlap. Essentially, `f` and `f2` represent totally different relationships between `x` and `y`. You can see this by plotting.

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   theme_set(theme_classic())

   ggplot(bind_rows(f=f,f2=f2, .id="source"), aes(x,y,colour=source)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_smooth(method="lm")
   ```

   [image]

   Also, there's no noise in the fake data, so the fit is perfect (RMSE = 0 and R-squared = 1).

   ```
   fit
   ```

   > ```
   > Resampling results:
   >
   >   RMSE          Rsquared
   >   1.650006e-15  1
   > ```
3. The fake data set has a continuous outcome variable. However, a confusion matrix is a tool for checking the quality of a classification model--that is, data where the outcome is categorical, rather than continuous. In that case, you would use a model like logistic regression, random forest, etc. appropriate for classification, rather than a linear regression model. Then you would use `confusionMatrix` to compare the predicted class to actual class.

Here's an example:

```
library(caret)

# Fake data
set.seed(100)
f = data.frame(y = c(rep(c("A","B"), c(100,25)),rep(c("B","A"), c(100,25))),
               x = c(rnorm(125, 1, 1), rnorm(125, 3, 1)))

# Train model on training data
set.seed(50)
idx = sample(1:nrow(f), 200)  # Indices of training observations
fit <- train(y ~ ., data = f[idx,], method="glm")

# Get predictions on probability scale
pred <- predict(fit, newdata=f[-idx, ], type="prob")

# Create data frame for confusion matrix
results = data.frame(pred=ifelse(pred$A < 0.5, "B","A"),
                     actual=f$y[-idx])

confusionMatrix(results$pred, results$actual)
```

> ```
> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
>
>           Reference
> Prediction  A  B
>          A 16  7
>          B  6 21
>
>                Accuracy : 0.74            
>                  95% CI : (0.5966, 0.8537)
>     No Information Rate : 0.56            
>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.006698        
>
>                   Kappa : 0.475           
>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.000000        
>
>             Sensitivity : 0.7273          
>             Specificity : 0.7500          
>          Pos Pred Value : 0.6957          
>          Neg Pred Value : 0.7778          
>              Prevalence : 0.4400          
>          Detection Rate : 0.3200          
>    Detection Prevalence : 0.4600          
>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.7386          
>
>        'Positive' Class : A
> ```